# I need to implement a application to do what instafeed.js do

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, instafeedjs

I have a web project that need to connect to my ig page and show the latest post on my website,
like what instafeed.js do

(instafeed.js repo: https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js)

as far as I know, ig close the apis that what instafeed use, and introduce 'Instagram Basic Display API'.

so i setup a server (named "api app") to try to solve oauth login and gain access.

now the thing is, I only want to use this api app to internal web, and I don't want to deploy this app to let other people use.

can I just setting this app under devolopment, and set add my page's account to test user, to let all my flow work ( that is, get my page's access token,  write an api to get page's photo, and show to my website?

production app need to set everything up and send  permission equests to fb and wait at list five days. that's annoying, and I certainly dont want this app is online and everyone can use it

Comment: When you are willing to think outside of the box you can find a nice answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60394300/2397550

Comment: Is it safe to add acess_token at the client-side? I think (and as per Instagram as well) it's not. Then how can we utilize instafeed.js without compromising on security?